# reverseGeocode - completionHandling a completionHandler? (Swift)

Tags: swift, reverse-geocoding, completionhandler

What is the best way to achieve this? I have a func that gets the reverseGeocode for a given longitude/latitude and it works just fine. But because it is asynchronous by the time it has got the address information I have already executed the lines to commit the address to a database. Do I need to completionHandle the completionHandler or is there some other way. I did try a do/while loop (don't laugh) and that didn't work.

```
func reverseGeocode() -> Bool {
    let geoCoder = CLGeocoder()
    let newLocation = CLLocation(latitude: valueLatitude, longitude: valueLongitude)
    geoCoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(newLocation, completionHandler: {(placemarks: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) in
    if error != nil {
        println("LocationsMenu - Geocode failed with error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
    if placemarks.count > 0 {
        let myplacemark         = placemarks[0] as! CLPlacemark
        let addressDictionary   = myplacemark.addressDictionary
        let address             = addressDictionary[kABPersonAddressStreetKey] as! NSString
        let city                = addressDictionary[kABPersonAddressCityKey] as! NSString
        let state               = addressDictionary[kABPersonAddressStateKey] as! NSString
        let postcode            = addressDictionary[kABPersonAddressZIPKey] as! NSString
        let country             = addressDictionary[kABPersonAddressCountryKey] as! NSString
        println("\(address) \(city) \(state) \(postcode) \(country)")
    }
    self.showMap(placemarks[0] as! CLPlacemark)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to move the code that commits your placemark information to the database inside your completion handler. If that code is called outside your reverseGeocode method, you can refactor `reverseGeocode` to take a block as a parameter. Then invoke that block inside your completion block (presumably inside your `if placemarks.count > 0` if block.)